# What's the relationship between a custom recovery and rooting?

Tags: rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery

So I want to make sure I understand everything.

If I want a Recovery, I need to root my phone. I have an LG G2. Clockwork is a recovery; If I download ClockworkMod recovery and use Flashify without rooting my phone, will that eventually root my phone through ClockworkMod flashing? Or should I root my phone with ioroot.zip first, and then flash a recovery?

Comment: Also, welcome to Android Enthusiasts! And congratulations: You've already mastered the one-post/one-question format that we follow here! Feel free to register and stick around.

Answer (score 1):

You **don't** need to root your phone in order to use a custom recovery like TWRP or ClockWorkMod.

It will only root your phone if you use it to...

- flash a rooted image
- flash a su binary
- restore a rooted backup

It is common for recoveries to offer to root when you restart, but you can just say "No" if you don't want to root.

Comment: So if I get Flashify, unrooted phone, I can take the Clockwork Image file and flash my phone successfully? And does Clockwork then afterwards ask to root? Doesn't Clockwork recovery come with the Superuser app (hence automatically rooting)?

Comment: ClockworkMod is just that: a recovery mod. So it installs to `/recovery`, while the `su` binary and the *SuperUser* / *SuperSU* app reside in `/system`. Both are completely independend partitions. So when *flashing the recover image*, it should only go to `/recovery` – and *might* offer you to root your device when *starting* it (i.e. "booting to recovery"). I never noticed the latter, though – but that might well be because I've always rooted first ;)

Comment: what rooting would you recommend? ioroot.zip?

Comment: We don't usually offer recommendations around here because it's based on opinion. Personally, I use [SuperSU](http://download.chainfire.eu/351/). You should also check out [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/how-do-i-root-my-android-device).